# Stretching words and quotation scoping

Tags: factor-lang

To play at [Stretch the word](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/77043/46231), I've defined the following words, to try to work at the problem via the same method as [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77064/46231):

```
USING: kernel math sequences sequences.repeating ;
IN: stretch-words

! "bonobo" -> { "b" "bo" "bon" "bono" "bonob" "bonobo" }
: ascend-string ( string -- ascending-seqs )
    dup length 1 + iota [ 0 swap pick subseq ] map
    [ "" = not ] filter nip ;

! expected: "bonobo" -> "bonoobbooo"
! actual:   "bonobo" -> "bbbooonnnooobbbooo"
: stretch-word ( string -- stretched ) 
    dup ascend-string swap zip
    [ 
      dup first swap last 
      [ = ] curry [ dup ] dip count 
      repeat 
    ] map last ;
```

`stretch-word` is supposed to repeat a character in a string by the number of times it's appeared up to that position in the string. However, my implementation is repeating *all* instances of the 1string it gets.

I have the feeling this is easily implementable in Factor, but I can't quite figure it out. How do I make this do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm... not a great golf, but it works...

First, I made a minor change to `ascend-string` so it leaves the string on the stack:

```
: ascend-string ( string -- string ascending-seqs )
    dup length 1 + iota [ 0 swap pick subseq ] map
    [ "" = not ] filter ;
```

So `stretch-word` can work like this:

```
: stretch-word ( string -- stretched ) 
    ascend-string zip         ! just zip them in the same order
    [ 
      first2 over             ! first2 is the only golf I could make :/
      [ = ] curry count       ! same thing
      swap <array> >string    ! make an array of char size count and make it a string
    ] map concat ;            ! so you have to join the pieces
```

---

Edit:
I think the problem was using repeat to do the job.

Comment: Sweet, thank you! A fresh set of eyes always helps. :D

Comment: @cat maybe if you use `map-index` and `head*` to make subsequences on each map step you'd be better?

Answer (score 1):

```
: ascend-string ( string -- seqs )
    "" [ suffix ] { } accumulate*-as  ;
: counts ( string -- counts )
    dup ascend-string [ indices length ] { } 2map-as ;
: stretch-word ( string -- stretched )
    [ counts ] keep [ <string> ] { } 2map-as concat ;
"bonobo" stretch-word print
bonoobbooo
```

`indices length` could also be `[ = ] with count`